# SQL - IN instead of UNION

Tags: sql, union

How can I achieve the same result set from the below query using `IN` instead of `UNION`?

```
select course_id 
from section 
where semester = 'Fall' 
  and year = '2009' 

union

select course_id 
from section 
where semester = 'Spring' 
  and year = '2010';
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Just `SELECT course_id FROM section WHERE (semester = 'Spring' AND year = '2010') OR (semester = 'Fall' AND year = '2009');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start with `or`:

```
select course_id
from section
where (semester = 'Fall' and year = '2009') or
      (semester = 'Spring' and year = '2010');
```

If a `course_id` could be on more than one row, then use `select distinct`.  The `union` does the `distinct` automatically.

Some databases support a tuple format, allowing you to do:

```
select course_id
from section
where (semester, year) in ( ('Fall', '2009'), ('Spring', '2010'));
```

Some, but not all.  So, this may or may not work on the database you are using.

Comment: I should use IN operator but !

Comment: As commented please tag your database in question. Future readers of that RDBMS may be interested in the tuple format.